# Damped & Negatively Damped harmonic oscillator with variable equilibrium position

Tags: differential-equations

I have the well known equation:

$$\frac{d^2Q(t)}{dt^2} + 2 \zeta \omega \frac{dQ(t)}{dt} + \omega^{2}Q(t) = 0, $$

where $\zeta= \frac {1}{4\pi}$,   $ \omega(t)= \frac{2\pi}{T(t)}= \frac{2\pi}{v(t)} \frac{dv}{dt}  $ and $v>0$ is a known parameter which is given from a data feed.

I have already built some visualization by using mathematica.

Consider now the mean value of Q over n period $ T(t)= \frac{2\pi}{w(t)}$:

$$ \overline Q_n(t)= \frac{1}{nT} \int_{0}^{nT}Q(t')dt' $$

Is there any method for solving this new equation:

$$\frac{d^2Y_n(t)}{dt^2} + 2 \zeta \omega \frac{dY_n(t)}{dt} + \omega^{2}Y_n(t) = 0, $$

where   $ Y_n =Q- \overline Q_n$

```
Manipulate[
C1[Q0_, q0_, w_] := -((-4*I*Pi*q0 - I*w*Q0 - Sqrt[-1 + 
 16*Pi^2]*w*Q0)/(2*Sqrt[-1 + 16*Pi^2]*w));
C2[Q0_, q0_, w_] := -((4*I*Pi*q0 + I*w*Q0 - Sqrt[-1 + 
 16*Pi^2]*w*Q0)/(2*Sqrt[-1 + 16*Pi^2]*w));
Func[t_, Q0_, q0_, w_] := C1[Q0, q0, w]/E^((I*t*((-I)*w + Sqrt[-1 + 
 16*Pi^2]*w))/(4*Pi))
 + E^((I*t*(I*w + Sqrt[-1 + 16*Pi^2]*w))/(4*Pi))*C2[Q0, q0, w];
Plot[{Func[t, Q0, q0, w1], Func[t, Q0, q0, w2]}, {t, 0, tmax},
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, Q},
 PlotLegends -> {"Volume increases", "Volume decreases"}],
{{tmax, 5, "plot time (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(max\)]\))"}, 0, 
 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{Q0, 10, "initial condition (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Q\), \ 
 (0\)]\))"}, 0, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{q0, 0, "initial change rate(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \ 
 (0\)]\))"}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{w1, 3.1415, "positive volume variation (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\ 
 [Omega]\), \(1\)]\))"}, 0, 6.2831, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{w2, -1.5708, "negative volume variation (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\ 
 [Omega]\), \(2\)]\))"}, -3.1415, 0, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
TrackedSymbols -> {tmax, Q0, q0, w1, w2}
]
```

Comment: You will get better answers if you show the code you used and the equation in MMA format.

Comment: Please provide Mathmatica code! What is the difference between `T[t] (defining omega)` and `T (mean Qn)`?

Comment: @Urich I am new to Mathematica. Which code other than the one i have posted do you need?